# How to have input recognize other types of variables?

Tags: python, variables

So here's a really quick program I though of writing down.

```
var = input ("Insert A Variable: ")

#Integer
if isinstance(var, int):
    VarType = "Integer"

#String
if isinstance(var, str):
    VarType = "String"

#List
if isinstance(var, list):
    VarType = "List"

#IDictionary
if isinstance(var, dict):
    VarType = "Dictionary"

print ("Variable Type: " + VarType + ".")
```

But, every input returns the `String` value, seeing `12` as `"12"`, `[]` as `"[]"`, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `eval()`, but this is discouraged as it is unprotected from "bad" input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `input()` always returns a string. You could use `ast.literal_eval()` to safely evaluate user input and `type()` to determine the type:

```
>>> import ast
>>> var = ast.literal_eval(input())
{}
>>> type(var)
<class 'dict'>
```

Or as [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) suggests, to fully handle bad inputs:

```
def get_type(prompt=''):
    text = input(prompt)
    try:
        T = type(ast.literal_eval(text))
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        T = str
    return T.__name__
```